# Move the 4th column in each row to next row in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with 4 columns(csv file) and n lines.

I want the 4th column values to move to the next line every time.
ex :
[LN],[cb],[I], [LS]

to

[LN],[cb],[I]

[LS]

*that is, if my file is:*

[LN1],[cb1],[I1], [LS1]

[LN2],[cb2],[I2], [LS2]

[LN3],[cb2],[I3], [LS3]

[LN4],[cb4],[I4], [LS4]

*the output file will look like*

[LN1],[cb1],[I1]

[LS1]

[LN2],[cb2],[I2]

[LS2]

[LN3],[cb2],[I3]

[LS3]

[LN4],[cb4],[I4]

[LS4]

**Test file:**

```
101 Xavier  Mexico City 41  88.0
102 Ann Toronto 28  79.0
103 Jana    Prague  33  81.0
104 Yi  Shanghai    34  80.0
105 Robin   Manchester  38  68.0
```

**Output required:**

```
101 Xavier  Mexico City 41  
88.0
102 Ann Toronto 28  
79.0
103 Jana    Prague  33  
81.0
104 Yi  Shanghai    34  
80.0
105 Robin   Manchester  38  
68.0
```

Comment: do you really need pandas? Is it a complex/quoted csv file? If not you can simply replace the last comma of each line with a newline

Comment: @mozway : it's a string file no quotes.

Comment: Then do as suggested. Can you please fix the formatting of the question? use backticks to format as code not quotes

Comment: thank you so much. I removed the quotes.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] meaning copy pastable sample data.

Comment: I have proved a test file

Answer (score 0):

Split the dataframe into 2 dataframes, one with the first 3 columns and the other with the last column. Add a new helper-column to both so you can order them afterwards. Now combine them again and order them first by index (which is identical for entries which where previously in the same row) and then by the helper column.

Since there is no test data, this answer is untested:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
s = """col1,col2,col3,col4
101 Xavier,Mexico City,41,88.0
102 Ann,Toronto,28,79.0
103 Jana,Prague,33,81.0
104 Yi,Shanghai,34,80.0
105 Robin,Manchester,38,68.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=',')

df1 = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].copy()
df2 = df[['col4']].rename(columns={'col4':'col1'}).copy()

df1['ranking'] = 1
df2['ranking'] = 2

df_out = df1.append(df2)
df_out = df_out.rename_axis('index_name').sort_values(by=['index_name', 'ranking'], ascending=[True, True])
df_out = df_out.drop(['ranking'], axis=1)
```

Comment: The last line command does not change anything. :/ . gives the same output as df_out in the previous line

Comment: @s8j try the updated code, I thinkt the , ignore_index=True was wrong

Comment: The final output provides 5 columns I need only 3 columns i.e gives the same output as df_out in the previous line. I have provided a test file if that helps.

Comment: @s8j, updated, should work now

Comment: it worked partly. so it moves the final column to the next line but in the next line, it moves to the final column(I want it to move to the  1st column i.e col1)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this is to convert the table to a list, then rearrange the list to reconstruct the table.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"test_file.csv")
df_list = df.values.tolist()


new_list = []
for x in df_list:
    # Removes last element from list and save it to a variable 'last_x'.
    # This action also modifies the original list
    last_x = x.pop()
    
    # append the modified list and the last values to an empty list.
    new_list.append(x)
    new_list.append([last_x])
    
    
# Use the new list to create the new table...
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_list)
```